# How to configure Keycloak 18 running http only in production mode?

Tags: keycloak

I have the situation that I run Keycloak 18.0.0 behind a reverse proxy that is terminating the secure (https) connection. Therefore I would like to build a Docker image that configures Keycloak to only listen on http (e.g. port 8080).

I have adjusted the `Dockerfile` from the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers). It uses

- MariaDB as database
- Enables Health and Metrics Endpoints
- Since I'm terminating the TLS connection in the reverse proxy I additionally make use of the `--proxy=edge` option, when starting Keycloak (see [Proxy Mode](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/keycloak.x/configuration.md#proxy-mode)).

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_DB=mariadb
# Install custom providers
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]
```

I then build my Docker image using

```bash
docker build --no-cache . -t ghcr.io/saw303/zscsupporter-be/keycloak-18.0.0:0.0.1
```

and start the image within my Docker Composition.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  proxy:
    image: caddy:2.5.1-alpine
    ports:
      - "${PROXY_IP}:80:80"
      - "${PROXY_IP}:443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:Z
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/caddy_data:/data:Z
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/caddy_config:/config:Z
  
  keycloak:
    image: ghcr.io/saw303/zscsupporter-be/keycloak-18.0.0:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9001:8080"
      - "127.0.0.1:9443:8443"
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 80
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://keycloakdb:3306/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_PROXY: edge

  keycloakdb:
    image: mariadb:10.7.3-focal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      TZ: "Europe/Zurich"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/mysql:rw
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3307:3306"
```

When I then start the Docker composition using

```bash
docker compose up -d && docker compose logs -f keycloak
```

I get the following log statement that clearly states that it uses **Strict HTTPS**.

```
backend-keycloak-1  | 2022-05-29 17:37:46,922 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: FrontEnd: localhost, Strict HTTPS: true, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin: localhost, Port: 8,080, Proxied: true
```

And when I access the administration console

```
http://localhost:9001/admin/master/console/
```

I get a blank page and the admin console sends only one request to

```
http://localhost:9001/admin/master/console/config
```

which returns wrong URLs `https:`.

```json
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "https://localhost:8080/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "security-admin-console",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Is there a way to change the protocol in field value `auth-server-url` from `https` to `http`?

**Update 1: Proxy configuration**

I use Caddy Server 2.0 as a reverse proxy. In this test setup caddy is part of the Docker composition and simply redirects all request on port `80` to the `keycloak` container on port `8080`.

```
{
  admin off
}

localhost:80

reverse_proxy /* keycloak:8080

log
```

Please note that the behaviour is the same whether I access the Keycloak admin console through the reverse proxy `localhost:80` or directly `localhost:9001`. When accessing it through the proxy I, of course change the port value `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 80`.

**Update 2: Set KC_PROXY in docker-compose.yml**

The `KC_PROXY` env variable is now set in the `docker-compose.yml` but the behaviour is the same. When I jump into the running `keycloak` container I see the following active configuration

```bash
➜  docker compose exec keycloak bash
WARN[0000] The "PROXY_IP" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "PROXY_IP" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
bash-4.4$ bin/kc.sh show-config
Current Mode: none
Runtime Configuration:
        kc.cache =  ispn (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.config.args =  show-config (SysPropConfigSource)
        kc.db =  mariadb (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.db.password =  secret (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.db.url =  jdbc:mariadb://keycloakdb:3306/keycloak (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.db.username =  keycloak (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.health-enabled =  true (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.home.dir =  /opt/keycloak/bin/../ (SysPropConfigSource)
        kc.hostname =  localhost (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.hostname.port =  80 (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.hostname.strict.backchannel =  true (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.http-enabled =  false (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
        kc.http-relative-path =  / (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.log-console-output =  default (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
        kc.log-file =  /opt/keycloak/bin/../data/log/keycloak.log (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
        kc.log.level =  info (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.metrics-enabled =  true (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.provider.file.keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar.last-modified =  1653899384311 (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.proxy =  edge (EnvConfigSource)
        kc.quarkus-properties-enabled =  false (PersistedConfigSource)
        kc.show.config =  none (SysPropConfigSource)
        kc.version =  18.0.0 (SysPropConfigSource)
```

The interesting part is that it indicates that http is disabled.

```
kc.http-enabled =  false (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
```

Comment: pls show  your proxy config

Comment: @JanGaraj proxy config added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it up and running on `localhost` by configuring the reverse proxy to use a self-signed certificate.

```
{
  admin off
}

localhost:443 {
        reverse_proxy keycloak:8080
        tls internal
}

log
```

The magic part with Caddy is to declare `tls internal`.

After that I changed my `Dockerfile` to this

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KC_DB=mariadb
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]
```

and my `docker-compose.yml` accordingly.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  proxy:
    image: caddy:2.5.1-alpine
    ports:
      - "${PROXY_IP}:80:80"
      - "${PROXY_IP}:443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:Z
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/caddy_data:/data:Z
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/docker-volume/caddy/caddy_config:/config:Z

  keycloak:
    image: ghcr.io/saw303/zscsupporter-be/keycloak-18.0.0:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9443:8443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://keycloakdb:3306/keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      KC_PROXY: edge

  keycloakdb:
    image: mariadb:10.7.3-focal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      TZ: "Europe/Zurich"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/mysql:rw
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3307:3306"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1.0"
          memory: 200M
```

After this configuration the access to the Keycloak Admin Console finally works. It seems like it is not possible to access the Admin Console with an non secure connection.

Comment: Hi @saw303 I just saw you answered it yourself... but my comment above is still valid ;) KC Team Member here. We know we messed up a bit, so to explain: Yes, in production mode we want to be "secure by design", so even when you use proxy=edge or http-enabled=true, you have to set hostname-strict-https=false. If you don't do that, the only other way is the way you did here, so basically redirecting http to https or adding another internal cert. There are ongoing discussions on the github repo, and I hope in the next major we will provide a better experience. :)

Comment: You can check this too: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/kc-17-x-x-how-to-access-admin-ui-from-port-forwarded-internal-url-prevent-redirect-from-internal-url-to-kc-hostname/14917/9

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Keycloak instance doesn't use `--proxy=edge` config.

Try official doc syntax: `--proxy edge` (of course translated to Dockerfile syntax) or simpler option is to set Keycloak container env variable `KC_PROXY: edge`

Comment: Setting the proxy via env variable has the same effect. I added the keycloak config at runtime to my question (see Update 2)

Comment: @saw303 so `KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"`

Comment: Another interesting thing is that I cannot overwrite the value using `kc.spi-hostname-default-strict-https=false` in my `conf/keycloak.conf`. It keeps on returning `true`.

Comment: `KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"` does not change the behaviour either. I'm a bit lost

Comment: @saw303 It should work setting `KC_PROXY=edge` and `KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version was causing my issue. The following config solved it in my docker-compose file:

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_CREATE_ADMIN_USER: true
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_DEBUG: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN: localhost
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgresql
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: kc
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health/ready" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      ebills-backend-network:
        aliases:
          - "keycloak"
    depends_on:
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
```

As mentioned in previous posts, the following url is helpful in debugging:

http://keycloak:8080//realms/master/hostname-debug