# Keycloak admin console loading indefinitely

Tags: keycloak, dev-to-production

I have a Keycloak server running in an EKS cluster that I'm trying to configure for production instead of dev mode.

I've managed to get SSL working with a reverse proxy, but when I go to the login page for the admin console it just loads indefinitely.

[image]

Here's my configuration:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1 as builder

ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM --platform=linux/arm64 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

## Install custom providers
COPY auth-identione-extension/target/auth-identione-extension-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/keycloak/providers

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_KEYCLOAK_USER={user}
ENV KC_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD={password}
ENV KC_DB_URL={dburl}
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME={dbusername}
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD={dbpassword}
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=auth.identione.com
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized"]
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: {keycloak-img-url}
          name: keycloak-app
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8180
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: {certificate-arn}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'https'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: auth.identione.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: keycloak-service
              servicePort: 8180
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the issue.

I had to move the `ENV KC_PROXY=edge` variable in the Dockerfile after running the build script.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I am facing the same issue and have KC_PROXY=edge as an env var

Comment: priceless advice ... .worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 2):

It was a nightmare to get it running following a lot of advisories. I tried to reduce the *docker-compose.yml* file - not to set some environment variables.

With this compose file I got 22.0.0 running. (BTW: version 18 didn't had so much troubles.)

Keep in mind that this is **only for developers**. The **security is** almost **shut down**. But for starting and development it serves.

Then you can access it locally via http://localhost:8888

Hint: This doesn't work via http://127.0.0.1:8888

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mariadb:11
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      MARIADB_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.0
    environment:
      keycloak.url: http://keycloak:8888
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8888
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mysql:3306/${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}?characterEncoding=UTF-8
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false
      HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_LOG: console
      KC_PROXY: none
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    command:
    - "start-dev"
    - "--http-port=8888"
    ports:
    - "8888:8888"


      
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8888/health/ready" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    
    
      
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

my *.env* file:

```
KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME=kc
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD=secret
KEYCLOAK_DB_USER=sa
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a related issue documenting this on their [GitHub](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14666) with specific instructions on how to debug this:

1. Start Keycloak with the `--hostname-debug=true` option.
   (Env var: `KC_HOSTNAME_DEBUG`.) [Documentation
   link](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config#category-hostname).
2. Browse to this URL: `KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL/realms/master/hostname-debug`

You would see an HTML table with a set of `[OK]` and `[Not OK]` next to frontend, backend, and admin.

A few pointers to help you debug this:

- All of the URLs must be HTTPS URLs. If using HTTP (and not HTTPS), all of the URLs must be HTTP.
- Try setting the right proxy value. If TLS terminates on a reverse proxy, use `edge`. You can read more about the other proxy options [here](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/self-serviced-end-to-end-encryption-approaches-for-applications-deployed-in-openshift).
- If you are using HTTPS, `--hostname-strict-https=false` must NOT be set, especially if your proxy setting is `edge`. Setting it to false will cause keycloak to generate HTTP URLs instead of HTTPs.

Answer (score 1):

Without docker and after old version upgrade my solution was the
private browser mode.

After loading showed error invalid redirect uri, but have chance it is another problem!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for Keycloak installation using Helm on Kubernetes

- Kubernetes version : `v1.27.2`
- Keycloak version installed using [Github » bitnami/keycloak](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak)

  - CHART_VERSION : `keycloak-16.1.1`
  - APP VERSION : `22.0.1`

#### Patch the configmap to add ENV KC_PROXY

```bash
# Get the configmap deployed for keycloak
$ kubectl get configmap -n <namespace>                        
NAME                DATA   AGE
keycloak-env-vars   15     xx

# Ensure you are doing it in the namespace where keycloak is deployed
kubectl patch configmap keycloak-env-vars -n <namespace> --type merge --patch '{"data":{"KC_PROXY":"edge"}}'

# Get the pod using configmap and restart the same
$ kubectl get pods -n <namespace>
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
keycloak-0              1/1     Running   0          xx
keycloak-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          xx

$ kubectl delete pod keycloak-0 -n <namespace>
```

- Wait for the pod to be restarted and try accessing the admin console again.

Comment: worked for me as well, even though I've set `proxy: edge` in the values file

Answer (score 1):

I also stucked on this for hours. I use traefik, letsencrypt and keycloak.

My final docker compose file that **worked**. Maybe this will help someone.

```
version: '3'


networks:
  portainer_default:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
    
volumes:
  postgres_keycloak_data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - portainer_default      
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${POSTGRES_DB}", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
      
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_HEALTH_ENDPOINTS: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_STATISTICS: 'true'
      KC_HOSTNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME}
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: 'false'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./ataccama_tellstory:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/themes/ataccama_tellstory
    command: ['start', '--optimized', '--http-port=8089', '--hostname-debug=true', '--hostname-strict=false']
    networks:
      - portainer_default
    ports:
      - "8089:8089" # Externe-Portnummer:Interne-Portnummer      
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 10s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8089' || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 90s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`${KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8089"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.middlewares=compresstraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.compresstraefik.compress=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-network"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running it locally with docker-compose and after referring to the comment from the accepted answer here [How to configure Keycloak 18 running http only in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426072/how-to-configure-keycloak-18-running-http-only-in-production-mode) , setting KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false it worked for me.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I get this error in the browser:
Refused to frame 'http://auth.identione.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".

Comment: Is it related to this https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12612 or https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10340?

Answer (score 0):

I am using standalone version of keycloak and resolved this by setting `--hostname-strict=false`

Example: awanish@192 bin % `./kc.sh start --db postgres --db-url-host localhost --db-username postgres --db-password change_me --hostname-strict=false --https-key-store-password=secret`

Answer (score 0):

there is an additional possible reason this can happen:
if you have a "KC_HOSTNAME" specified (or hostname via cli arguments)
and that hostname is an unsafe certificate
and you originally call the sie via the ip

then during that spinner the keycloak will start calling the requests via the hostname and if it is not yet trusted will result in an endless spinner

in that case simply open the "hostname" page manually and accept the risk of an unsafe certificate

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a mix of:

- Exposing the service on port 80 (instead of 8080)
- Setting the right hostname (static IP on LAN)

I'm running it on a k3s cluster and deploying it via ArgoCD. No config map, just env vars injected directly in the deployment.

Let's say I'm exposing the keycloak service on IP 192.168.2.123, then the value for KC_HOSTNAME should match that IP address. If you have a domain name, you can set that instead ofcourse.

Here is my full config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
          args: ["start-dev"]
          env:
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: SEE_COMMENT
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
```