# Keycloak admin console not working internal it gives "Loading the admin console"

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, amazon-eks

I am having keycloak installed and working in Prod and we are currently migrating to Kubernetes(EKS) so I used Bitnami chart and used the same config as in Prod but admin console not working internally I tried version 19.0.0 and 20.0.0

here is the  keycloak config

```
  KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE: **
  KC_PROXY: edge
  KC_DB: postgres
  KC_DB_URL_HOST: **
  KC_DB_USERNAME: ***
  KC_HOSTNAME: public_url
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
  KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: public_url
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
  KK_TO_RMQ_URL: **
  KK_TO_RMQ_USERNAME: **
  KK_TO_RMQ_PASSWORD: **
  KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_URL: **
  KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: true
  KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN: internal_url
```

in the Docker file I give start --proxy edge

here is the error that comes in the browser

> Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message.
> Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

I am trying to get keycloak admin console to work internally but it keeps loading forever without opening the admin dashboard

I also tried the fix on the thread [Keycloak admin console loading indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883728/keycloak-admin-console-loading-indefinitely)
but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue, and here is the solution explained:

1. I removed the admin console internal connection configuration to dig more
2. I was using Bitnami chart for keycloak in the Bitnami chart there is a config like that

   ```
    containerSecurityContext:
      enabled: true
      runAsUser: 1001
      runAsNonRoot: false
   ```
3. as keycloak needs to create tmp folder for caching the css and js files it was not able to create it

   > KC-SERVICES0075: Failed to get theme request: java.lang.RuntimeException: Temporary directory /opt/keycloak/bin/../data/tmp does not exist and it was not possible to create it
4. so I disabled this feature in bitnami

   ```
    containerSecurityContext:
      enabled: false
   ```
5. set the user in the image as keycloak or any other privileged user

and that's it, now working as a charm.